# Swiftkey app does not work inside Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

So heres the deal: I am getting to know the functionalities of the Webivew in Android and I've been testing with some well known urls and everything works fine. I've also added the onsavedInstanceState and onBackPressed methods to make sure I can go back to the previous page and make sure the page does no reload.

Problem:
    Lets say I load the Facebook url and I am posting something, **The SwiftKey Dictionary does not show**. Is there a way to work around this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the question only for facebook?

Comment: IM sorry I should have cleared that. No, any website that allows me to interact by typing things (either comment news, facebook,etc.) the SwiftKey does not work.

Comment: And Im guessing that any other app like Swiftkey wont work but Im not 100% sure.